# Hook JDBC Connection.Close() Method

Tags: jdbc, connection, hook

I have a requirement to Hook the excisting class methods and do some sort of logging. The classes are written and placed as Jars in the Application. A Typical example on my scenario is as follows.

1. We open a connection(java.sql.Connection) and close the connection when all the DB opertaions are completed. What I want here is to call a custom method on every call to Connection.close() method. I could not create custom classed for the connection since code changes for this will be very huge in the excisting project.

Is there a way to Hook the Close method. Is it possible to hook method in Java?

Any help is appreciated.! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways:

- Use [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) and have the InvocationHandler do additional things when `close()` is called
- Write a wrapper extending `Connection` (essentially the same as Proxy, except you have to implement all methods yourself and link them to the contained Connection)
- I have never used it, but I believe AspectJ allows you to add behavior using [pointcuts](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html#pointcuts)

Comment: Wrote a Wrapper class extending the java.sql.Connection class and implemented all the method calling the Super class method.